# How to send large data using get method?

Tags: javascript, java

I have to send an json array whixh length is above 2kb(limit of GET method=2kb) but when i use post method the file download dialog box is not appering as the file is download in working directory
 and when i use get method download box is appered but pdf is null.Is anyone provide me the solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in most of cases (few techno allow it like elasticsearch), we can not send a json request body in a get method. Why you don't use a Post? you can send and get the json you want.

Comment: thank you but i use base64 convertion method and convert my file using base64 and display it..

Comment: Okay :) by the way, I saw that jdk 9 will offer interesting base64 handling.